# How to restore Oracle DB with CA ArcServe Backup 16.5?

Tags: backup, oracle, restore

I am trying to restore a table from Oracle DB (version 10.2). The Oracle DB is being backed up by using full + differential backups with CA ARCserve 16.5.

The problem is that I don't find an option in ARCserve to restore only a table or to restore the whole DB instance on an alternative location. It says the only possibility is to restore the DB in place. So the current data would be replaced. Of course, that is out of the question and it is not a suitable approach.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to restore from Linux + Oracle.

Procedure

Every backup has a unique TAG which can be found by running a simple rman query

RMAN> list backup of database completed after 'SYSDATE -1';

This will list all the backups done today along with the TAG number as shown in the red box.

[image: RMAN> list backup of database completed after 'SYSDATE -1';]

In the oracle agent restore options we can enter the TAG in the box RESTORE FROM BACKUP TAG as shown below

[image: Oracle Agent]

Submit the job and it will run the restore from the specific media as shown from the oragentd log in the figure below

![Jobstrong text][3]

The red box indicates that the restore used the backup with the TAG specified.

Comment: The third image is missing.